# How to know if the image has loaded in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to find out where exactly the image has finished loading I am using state to update the src of the img jsx component any idea how to deal with this ?

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(context.img);
  }, [context.img]);

<div
                id='image'
                style={{
                  /* This image is 687 wide by 1024 tall, similar to your aspect ratio */
                  backgroundImage: `url(${loaded})`,
                  height: pdf ? 150 : '30vw',
                  width: pdf ? 150 : '30vw',
                  maxWidth: 150,
                  maxHeight: 150,
                  backgroundSize: 'cover',
                  backgroundPosition: 'center top',
                  borderRadius: '50%',
                }}
                //src={loaded}
                onLoad={() => {
                  setLoading(false);
                  console.log('do other stuff here if you want');
                }}
              />
              {loading && <spinner style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />}
            </div>
```

Comment: The onload event seems the right way to achieve this. But I don't understand exactely what is your question ?

Comment: it is not working due to the use on style props since I am using mui

Comment: if I use src it works but i want to keep certain style , so i am using the backgroundImage

Comment: Looks like your post is lacking some details to explain your problem, what's not working, why, what you tried, what you use etc

Comment: If you use a background image, why do you use an <img> element ? Its seems weird to set a background for an image with its own src.

Comment: I updated the code so you can see more about the current styling and want to use div, the issue is i want to target the img that will load in to the div !

Comment: Oooh ok, so you want to detect the moment css will have resolve the given url. In that case I don't know if using a css property is a good idea because I don't think you ca nget any onload event from css. Maybe you should create an Image() object in your component, load the url and handle everythink from that, with pure js.

Comment: ok I will try good point